# Vue-router - How to cancel operations when user clicked menu links

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

Not specific to Vue.js but to Javascript Single Page applications. If you have a form and a rather long running submit action, like saving something. The submit operation should save something and then pushing to a new route for a success message.

While waiting for the result, the user clicks on a different link and is going away.

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hajbgt28/4/

```
const Home = { 
  template: '<div><button @click="submit">Save and go Bar!</button></div>',
  methods: {
     async submit() {
            await setTimeout(() => {
           this.$router.push("/bar");
        }, 5000);
     }
  }
};
const Foo = { template: '<div>Foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>Bar</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

1. Click Home
2. Click the button
3. Click on "Foo" immediately, you see "Foo"
4. Wait a few seconds
5. The Page changes to "Bar"

I have a two solutions in my mind:

- I can check inside the submit operation if I am still on the route I expect and only proceed if the user is still on this page. It is rather complicated to check it every time
- Disable all links on the page while loading. But this makes the page useless until the operation is finished.

What is the best practice for situations like this?

Comment: You could also use a modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `beforeRouteLeave` [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to abort that action (i.e., cancel the timer in your example) upon switching routes.

1. Assuming identifiable submit actions, save the ID of the operation result (*i.e., save the timer ID from `setTimeout`'s return value in your example*).
2. Add a `beforeRouteLeave` handler to the component to cancel the submit action (*i.e., clear the timer ID in your example*).

```
const Home = {
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.timerId /* 1 */ = setTimeout(() => {
        this.$router.push("/bar");
      }, 5000);
    }
  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    clearTimeout(this.timerId) /* 2 */
    next()
  }
};
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa0zo2jv/1/)

Comment: This isn't very practical unless the OP literally intended on making his users wait 5 seconds. Most likely he was using `setTimeout` as a placeholder for an actual form submission, and cancelling that would look different from a `clearTimeout`.

Comment: @RobertMoore I'm assuming `setTimeout` was just a representation of an async operation (i.e., the "submit operation" mentioned in question), and I'm following that example in my answer regardless of practicality. The OP could deduce using the corresponding cancel method to abort the operation.

Comment: I guess, you are both right. Both answers helped me a lot, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea: make a component that provides (using Vue's `provide`/`inject` API):

1. A function that starts an operation. This is called when a form is sent. It provides a `whenDone` callback which is either executed or ignored, depending on if the operation is cancelled.
2. A function that cancels all pending operations. The cancel function could be called when the user navigates away.

The implementation could look like this:

```js
const CancellableOperationProvider = {
  name: "CancellableOperationProvider",
  props: {},
  data: () => ({
    pendingOperations: []
  }),
  /*
   * Here we provide the theme and colorMode we received
   * from the props
   */
  provide() {
    return {
      $addOperation(func) {
        this.pendingOperations.push(func);
        func(function whenDone(callback) {
          if (this.pendingOperations.includes(func)) callback();
        });
      },
      $cancelAllOperations() {
        this.pendingOperations = [];
      }
    };
  },
  render() {
    return this.$slots.default[0];
  }
};
```

The usage would look like this:

```js
const Home = { 
  template: '<div><button @click="submit">Save and go Bar!</button></div>',
  inject: ['$addOperation', '$cancelAllOperations'],
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      this.$addOperation(whenDone => {
        await setTimeout(() => {
          whenDone(() => this.$router.push("/bar"));
        }, 5000);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

You could then add a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to the Vue Router so that `$cancelAllOperations` is called after clicking any link. Since `$cancelAllOperations` is only accessible through the `inject` API you will have to make a component that imperatively adds a navigation guard to the Vue router after mounting and removes it when unmounting.

Let me know if it doesn't work--I haven't done Vue in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer from tony19 to make solution which fits my needs for use cases without setTimeout too:

```
const Home = { 
  template: '<div><button @click="submit">Save and go Bar!</button></div>',
  data() {
    return {
        onThisPage: true
    }
  },
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    this.onThisPage = false;
    next();
  },
  methods: {
     submit() {
           setTimeout(() => {
           if (this.onThisPage) {
                this.$router.push("/bar");
           }
        }, 5000);
     }
  }
};
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ovmse1jg/

Comment: Note that you don't need to `await` on `setTimeout` because the return value is just a literal (not a `Promise`).