How can I prevent Navigate forward?
I currently have a beforeunload event handler which exists when a form is dirty. it correctly blocks page a "Refresh" and navigating "Back", but navigate "Forward" is not prevented.
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
})

This can happen if a user navigates back and starts filling out a form, I need to warn them that their data is not saved will be lost if they navigate forward again.
I thought about using popstate but that wont work either https://stackoverflow.com/a/32432366/10917416
Is there another event fired when Navigating forward?
Update: I tested this with native html/js and it works as expected, this has something to do with the way vue/inertia handle history. VueRouter is NOT the issue as i am only using it in my example, the production app is using inertia as a router
The issue is something to do with window.history.pushState when i call that in the console the browser back/forward buttons dont trigger the beforeunload event
Update2: i added this bit of code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388878/10917416 to log all events, and the only event called when i press "forward" is popstate

The question needs a way to reproduce because this "navigate "Forward" is not prevented" is not true, afaik

I'll see if I can reproduce in a small example repo, I cant upload the repo of my project

@EstusFlask I added an example url where you can see the issue, and git for the code

Another Issue I just noticed; if you navigate forward then state is cleared, but the cleanup function is never run so the beforeunload is still registered even though when you go back the form is empty

Try this, since you are using Vue, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898739/11849262
you can add your check using this. Hope this helps.

@RawSlugs The comment above is right in the sense that route navigation and window unloading are two different cases that need to be treated separately. You don't unload a window when you navigate through SPA with history API that the router uses

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159482/vue-router-how-to-cancel-operations-when-user-clicked-menu-links

@EstusFlask, this is not a duplicate of that question. This has nothing to do with vue router. It's an issue with bfcache using native browser buttons, clicking fwd button in the browser is not prevented with beforeunload. My example was just a quick way to setup your browser with a history state.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77299348/beforeunload-equivalent-for-popstate which would suggest this is not possible

Don't mess with the forward/back expectations of users? Instead, whenever the current view's state changes, also run a history.replaceState, so that when a navigation does happen, there is no problem: you already had the correct state stored, and you can pop that as needed during forward/back actions by the user. The worst thing you can do is to only update the state way too late, when the user is already in the process of navigating away from the current view. Handle state updates all at the same time, including updating the browser state.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is a very specific situation where I'm not sure how history.replaceState can help. 1. User is on a page with a form, 2. user clicks a link to a new page which can be for anything, 3. user clicks the back button on the browser (this is not a navigation handled by my app, the user is just "traversing" back in the history), 4. the user starts filling out the form and for whatever reason decides he needs to go "back" to the page he was just on (2.) so he clicks the browsers forward button. is history traversing handled by the router or native to the browser?

@RawSlugs Then the demo is not representative, because you can prevent navigation within the app via router hooks. If you want to prevent from navigating to/from the website, that's another thing. The demo mentions safari but the question says nothing about this. Is this what the problem is? This is very specific to a browser then. In the worst case scenario of bfcache, which safari AFAIK is, you can't do much. It may not even allow to detect it with pagehide and beforeunload. I guess, this is to make sure navigation isn't blocked by malicious sites because apple knows better.

@RawSlugs Can the situation from the previous comment be reproduced in the demo?

@EstusFlask, i mentioned safari because safari had slightly different behavior than chrome. router hooks will not work as my issue is with the browsers back/forward buttons which dont trigger the router events. its not necessarily about navigating to/from the website, its preventing navigation the history.

the only event that runs on all browsers when clicking the back/forward buttons is popstate. I have read through the docs of inertiajs (which is the router in my primary project) and they mention that what i'm trying to do is not possible...

@RawSlugs I see. This wouldn't be a problem for plain vue with vue router like your demo showed. With regular SPA routing, there is no need to cancel popstate. When the navigation is "cancelled", the router just listens to popstate and redirects back to the previous location with history pushState. What happens with url doesn't affect the application state. And the real problem to lose the state would be non-history navigation, which can be handled with beforeunload, this is what was discussed above.

If your case is primarily inertia, this limits the way this could work. Not because "browsers do not allow cancelling the native popstate" but because inertia's client side router doesn't have complex lifecycle that would allow to handle this properly. So the answer is indeed that you can't, at least without messing with inertia's internals

Btw found this issue, this is is exactly what's discussed there https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/discussions/1648

https://inertiajs.com/events#cancelling-events
"Note, browsers do not allow cancelling the native popstate event, so preventing forward and back history visits while using Inertia.js is not possible."
Thanks @EstusFlask https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/discussions/1648
